# Mongoid + Devise Daily Signups

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, mongodb, devise, mapreduce, mongoid

I have been using Mongoid in my latest project along with Devise.  So far it is great.

I would like to count the number of user signups per day grouped by created_at date.

I know that in mongoDB it does not have a traditional group like a relational DB does and uses Map/Reduce for such queries.

I could do this by using pure ruby and looping across a range of dates but would really like to generate this information using the aggregation framework in MongoDB but having a bit of trouble doing it.

Could anyone give me an example of how to get a count of documents with Mongoid using map reduce based on the created at date?

Thanks

Tony

Comment: It does have a group: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/aggregation/group/#stage._S_group

Comment: Thanks for this but I am having a bit of trouble figurin out how to use to to group by days. Can you help at all?

Comment: I only know how to do it in console not ruby, if you were to give your schema over I could write a console answer

Comment: I am using Devise with Mongoid and this outlines the schema:

https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Upgrade-to-Devise-2.0-migration-schema-style#mongoid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have [a blog post](http://www.kamsky.org/1/post/2013/03/stupid-date-tricks-with-aggregation-framework.html) describing how to group by day (or any other truncation of a datetime field) using the aggregation framework.

What you need to do in a nutshell is to use $project stage to convert your created_at field into a "date" value (or one that reflects midnight of a particular date) and then $group with the date as _id while doing {$sum:1} to get the count of users.

Comment: Awesome.  I got it from your example.  Thanks a million!!